# Trying to add totals of multiple rows from a select statement

Tags: sql-server

At the very bottom in the last SELECT statement is where I want to have the total quantity listed. I want to add up the result of the OP.TotalQuantity aka total_number_of_units, row and have that number listed at the bottom of the table. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to total up the rows though...

```
USE [uStore]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Receipt_GetOrderItemsTable_PLB]    Script Date: 3/3/2016 4:39:56 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    -- =============================================
    -- Author:      <Blake Norwood,,Name>
    -- Create date: <03-03-16,,>
    -- Description: <Description,,>
    -- =============================================
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Receipt_GetOrderItemsTable_PLB]
        @OrderID int,
        @CultureID int
    AS
    DECLARE @Rows nvarchar(max)
    SET @Rows = ''

SELECT @Rows = 
    @Rows + '<tr><td>' + 
    CASE
        WHEN P.ProductDisplayID IS NULL
        THEN PC.Name  
        ELSE replace(replace(PD.Format, '{0}', PC.Name), '{1}', IsNull(P.CatalogNo, ''))
    END + 
    CASE 
        WHEN OP.CustomerNickName IS NOT NULL
        THEN ' - ' + OP.CustomerNickName 
        ELSE ''
    END +
    '</td><td>' + cast(OP.NumRecipients AS nvarchar) + '</td><td>' + 
    ISNULL(cast(OP.QuantityPerRecipient AS nvarchar) + ' ' + dbo.fn_GetProductUnitName(OP.QuantityPerRecipient, OP.ProductUnitID, @CultureID), '-') + 
    '</td><td>' + cast(OP.TotalQuantity AS nvarchar) + ' ' + dbo.fn_GetProductUnitName(OP.TotalQuantity, OP.ProductUnitID, @CultureID) + '</td><td>' + 
    Case When DM.Name != 'Void' Then dbo.fn_GetLocalizedText(DM.StringID, @CultureID) Else dbo.fn_GetLocalizedText('Receipt_NoDelivery', @CultureID) End + '</td><td>' + IsNull(dbo.fn_GetFormattedPriceForOrderProduct(OP.ProductPriceSubtotal, OP.OrderProductID, @CultureID), '-') + '</td></tr>'
From OrderProduct OP 
JOIN Product P ON P.ProductID = OP.ProductID
Join Product_Culture PC ON P.ProductID  = PC.ProductID AND PC.CultureID = @CultureID
Join DeliveryMethod DM ON OP.DeliveryMethodId = DM.DeliveryMethodId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductDisplay PD ON PD.ProductDisplayID = P.ProductDisplayID
WHERE 
    OP.OrderID = @OrderID AND
    OP.IsDraft = 0 AND
    OP.StatusID <> 2


SELECT
    '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%" border="1">' + 
    '<tr><td>' + dbo.fn_GetLocalizedText('product', @CultureID) + '</td><td>' + dbo.fn_GetLocalizedText('number_of_Recipients', @CultureID) + '</td><td>' + dbo.fn_GetLocalizedText('Quantity_Per_Recipient', @CultureID) + '</td><td>' + dbo.fn_GetLocalizedText('total_number_of_units', @CultureID) + '</td><td>' + dbo.fn_GetLocalizedText('delivery_service', @CultureID) + '</td><td>' + dbo.fn_GetLocalizedText('Subtotal', @CultureID) + '</td></tr>' + 
    @Rows + 
    '<tr><td>' + '<b>TOTAL</b>' + '</td><td>' + '</td><td>' + '</td><td>' + sum(TotalQuantity) + ' Items' + '</td><td>' + '</td><td>' + '</td></tr>' + 
    '</table>' AS [TABLE]
```

Comment: Seriously who writes HTML directly in a stored procedure?

Comment: I didn't write that code. It's from an application from Xerox. I agree though. It's kinda ridiculous. But I'm not smart enough to rewrite all their code.

Comment: Wow really?...that is insane.

Comment: Apparently I should have said it wasn't my poor code up front... Getting downvoted till I won't get an answer isn't cool...

Comment: It maybe that but not necessarily, as far as questions go it ain't the best. Maybe have a look at [ask]

Comment: I'm not really sure if this is what you're asking for, but one way of doing it could be adding another variable (e.g. `DECLARE @Total INT`), and add it into your select statement (e.g. something like `, @Total = SUM(OP.TotalQuantity) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT 1))` before the FROM. Then put that wherever you want in your table.  Alternatively, replace the thing you have in your table creation with a select statement (e.g. `SELECT CAST(SUM(OP.TotalQuantity) AS NVARCHAR(255)) FROM OrderProduct OP JOIN.... WHERE...` so that it's the same as the other select statement.

Comment: @Lankymart Ah, reading back through my post I see that it was a very poorly worded question! I posted it at the end of the day just on a whim as I was leaving work... I should have just waited till I had a clear head.

Comment: @ZLK THANK YOU. This worked. Just had to convert `@Total` to an nvarchar and I was able to output to the receipt. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the proc HAS to return HTML you could use a temporary table to store all the rows with a column for the sub-total and then total the sub-totals using Sum and For XML.  This is a basic snippet to should you what I mean, you'd have to adapt it.

```
create table #tmpRows
( tr varchar(100),
subTotal int
)
--test data, here you'd need to adapt your "select @rows =" statement
insert into #tmpRows
(tr, subTotal)
values ('<tr><td>test row 1</td></tr>', 45)
insert into #tmpRows
(tr, subTotal)
values ('<tr><td>test row 2</td></tr>', 55)
insert into #tmpRows
(tr, subTotal)
values ('<tr><td>test row 3</td></tr>', 65)
go
declare @rows varchar(2000)
declare @total varchar(200)
declare @ret varchar(2200)
select @rows =
         substring(
                (
                    Select ',' + tr + '<td></td>' AS [text()]
                    from #tmpRows
                    For XML PATH ('')
                ), 2, 1000) , @total= '<tr><td></td><td>' +  convert(varchar(10),sum(subtotal)) + '</td></tr>'
                from #tmpRows
select @ret =  replace( @rows + @total,'&lt;', '<')
select @ret = replace(@ret,'&gt;', '>')
select @ret
```